Where were the US-based scenes in "The Walking Dead: Daryl Dixon" filmed?
The Walking Dead: Daryl Dixon (2023) primarily takes place in France, following Daryl’s adventures in a new setting. While most of the series was filmed on location in France, there are a few flashback scenes of Daryl in the US and scenes featuring Carol searching for him stateside.
Season 1

Season 2



I’ve found plenty of information about the filming locations of the scenes set in France (examples: [1] [2] [3]) but can’t find any details about where the scenes set in the US were shot. Considering that TV productions often aim to minimize costs by limiting filming to a particular region, I’m curious about where these American scenes were actually filmed. For instance, the original The Walking Dead continued filming in Georgia, USA, long after the story had moved beyond that state. This makes me wonder if The Walking Dead: Daryl Dixon used a similar cost-saving strategy for its US scenes.
Interestingly, in the "Inside the Episode" video for Season 2, Episode 1 (which is mostly set in the US), director Greg Nicotero mentions that shooting the episode "was a challenge because [they] shot it [there] in France." So we know that at least for Season 2, Episode 1, the US-based scenes (New England) were shot in France. The location manager added that the filming took place "close to Paris."
For the Season 1 scenes, were they actually filmed in the US, perhaps in Georgia like the original series? If so, where exactly? Or did they find suitable locations in France to stand in for American settings (like in Season 2, Episode 1)? If it’s the latter, I’d love to know which parts of France were used to recreate the US backdrop.
Where were the US-based scenes in The Walking Dead: Daryl Dixon Season 1 and 2 filmed?
